# Test fail with Xcode Bots but works locally

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-bots

I have a test case that tests if a scene is loaded:

```
-(void)testThatSceneIsLoaded
{
    SCNScene *scene = [_sut newSceneWithName:@"Model.dae"];
    XCTAssertNotNil(scene, @"The scene hasn't been loaded");
}
```

And the method it's testing looks like this:

```
-(SCNScene*)newSceneWithName:(NSString*)name
{
    return [SCNScene sceneNamed:name];
}
```

The tests succeeds (as expected) when running the tests locally. But when my Xcode bot is running the tests it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does the bot output say?

Comment: Well, it fails. So it says that it's nil :)